# Predict height of element with added class before adding it

Tags: javascript

How do I simulate a added class to an element to get its height with this new class?

As an example:
We've got a `navigation` element with a dynamic height. This height changes when added e.g. `.navigation--fixed` class. I now want to get the new height of this element with this added class before adding this class. Some kind of predicting/simulating how a element will look with an added class.

Comment: Just add the class, and then retrieve the height. The DOM is updated before retrieving, but isn't re-rendered before the script will be executed. That allows you to retract the class addition if needed.

Comment: If for some strange reason you don't want to add the class, you can access the stylesheet and get the height set for the class, or you can clone the element and get the height without modifying the original element etc.